# Parse XML using xmllint displaying multiple keys

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmllint

I have the following xml:

```
<suite>
<suite total="3" errors="2">
    <case class="abc" name="123">
        <error type="Error"></error>
    </case>
    <case class="abc" name="456">
    </case>
    <case class="abc" name="789">
        <error type="Error"></error>
    </case>
</suite>
<suite>
   ...
</suite>
```

I want to extract the information so that the final solution looks like this :

```
abc/123 abc/789
```

i.e. print the `class/name` if the error tag exists.

I have been able to get the class or the name separately using the command :

```
echo 'cat //suite[@errors!="0"]/case[error[@type="Error"]]/@name' | xmllint --shell <file-path>
```

Is there a way to get both class and name in the required format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution that i came up with was:

```
failed=$(echo 'cat //suite[@errors!="0"]/case[error[@type="Error"]]/@*' | xmllint --shell <file-path> | awk '{if (NR %3 != 0) print $1 }' | awk '/^[nc]/' | awk -F'[="]' '{print $(NF-1)}'| awk '{if (NR%2!=0) printf " -i " $1; else printf "/"$1}')
```

The actual format required was  `-i class/name`

Also, the xml contained 3 attributes instead of 2 in the case tag (class,name,time)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with `xmllint` and XPath 1.0 but can be done with a little help of `bash`

```
echo 'ls //suite[@errors!="0"]/case[error[@type="Error"]]/@*' | xmllint --shell test.xml | gawk '/^ta/{ print $3 }' | sed '$!N;s/\n/\//'
```

Result:

```
abc/123
abc/789
```

Basically, it's parsing the output of `ls` in `xmllint` shell

```
ta-        3 abc
ta-        3 123
ta-        3 abc
ta-        3 789
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the gawk and sed commands are doing. My XML is not exactly the same as I wrote in the answer (its pretty big) so maybe thats why i am getting unexpected result

Comment: The size of the XML file does not matter, this should work as long as both attributes are in the same element. `gawk` is printing the 3rd field, `sed` is joining output every 2 lines.

Comment: Actually i meant that it has more attributes than the ones mentioned. Anyways i figured it out using awk. Finally used this: `failed=$(echo 'cat //suite[@errors!="0"]/case[error[@type="Error"]]/@*' | xmllint --shell <file-path> | awk '{if (NR %3 != 0) print $1 }' | awk '/^[nc]/' | awk -F'[="]' '{print $(NF-1)}'| awk '{if (NR%2!=0) printf " -i " $1; else printf "/"$1} END {print ""}')` Actual format required was " -i class/name".